# how to check exactly one value is greater than other in jquery? if so than alert box is show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one text field and one dropdown. in text field if anyone enter integer of floating numbers but in dropdown there are only two values 4 and 5. how i check if textfield value is greater than cropdown then alert box is show ? its working if a number is entered is less then 10 but if number is greater then or equal to 10 then its not working.

```
    $("#total_CGPA").blur(function(){  
        if($("#obt_CGPA").val() > $("#total_CGPA").val()) 
        { 
            alert("Obtained CGPA cannot greater than total CGPA");
            $("#obt_CGPA").val('');
            $("#obt_CGPA").focus();
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;    
        }
    }); 

<input name="obt_CGPA" type="text" id="obt_CGPA" maxlength="4"  placeholder="CGPA"/>

<select name="total_CGPA" id="total_CGPA" >
       <option value="">Select</option>
       <option value="4" >4</option>
       <option value="5" >5</option>
</select>
```

demo

http://jsfiddle.net/yWN4e/1/

Comment: have a look at `parseInt()`

Answer (score 2):

You first need to convert values to integer using [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) in if condition :

> ```
>   if( parseInt($("#obt_CGPA").val()) > parseInt($("#total_CGPA").val()) )
> ```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rjwsjd65/)**